# Refreshing WinForms Controls Bound to BindingSource (Bound to Object) After Data Source is Changed

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a winform that has controls bound to a bindingsource called MemberBS which is bound to a custom object called DomainModel.Member. The member object is bound to a table in a sql server database called members.

Among the controls on the form i have 4 textboxs, They are bound as follows.

```
        DuesOwingCE.DataBindings.Add("Text", MemberBS, "DuesOwing", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        InitOwingCE.DataBindings.Add("Text", MemberBS, "InitOwing", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        OtherOwingCE.DataBindings.Add("Text", MemberBS, "OtherOwing", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        AmountOwingCE.DataBindings.Add("Text", MemberBS, "AmountOwing", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

the user clicks on a button to enter transactions. I pass the member object of the member currently being edited to the dialog box. The user enters transactions for the member and then clicks Save. The Save button calls a method called CalculateOwing. This method recalculates the dues, initiation, other and total owing for the member, saves the member object which in turns commits the save to the underlying datasource.

The transaction form closes and the user is back on the member form. Now how do i get the textboxs to update so that the new balances are showing. I have tried MemberBS.ResetBindings(false) but that doesnt work.

Is the only solution to reload the object again from the datasource

MemberBS.DataSource = Repository.GetMember(socSecNo);

or is there a better one?

Answer (score 0):

To enable your controls to automatically reflect the dynamic changes of the binding source, your class needs to provide the proper property changed notifications. [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229614%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) shows how to create a class that implements **INotifyPropertyChanged**. For concept see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xz45s2bh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

When implemented, the interface communicates to a bound control the property changes on a business object.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old thread... Personally, I used the bindingsource.ResetBindings(false) with an Invoke call to refresh my controls.

for example:

```
if (InvokeRequired)
{
     this.Invoke(new Action(()=>this.bindingSource.ResetBindings(false)));
}
else
{
     this.bindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
}
```